# How to replace default cursor style with custom cursor in android

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-webview

Currently I am working on android note taking application for this i used **WebView** for **WYSIWYG editor** since I need custom cursor instead of platform default one.

index.html

```
<body><div id="editor" contenteditable></div></body>
```

In NoteActivity.onCreate() method i just called necessary methods on WebView instance.

[image]

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Kindly update your code.How you have implemented in webview.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.